# Search only files that I own

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need the script to recognize that it should only search for files I created, because I'm not allowed to delete other people's files in this Google Drive folder.

```
var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');
```

I confess that I tried to adjust by myself, but in every way is giving error, something always goes wrong. That form was my last attempt, which also failed:

```
var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '" and "me@gmail.com" in owners ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is working for me on a folder that I have shared with one other account.

```
function getMyFilesFromFolder() {
  var myFolderId = "FolderId";
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var myFiles=[];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if(file.getOwner().getEmail()==Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
      myFiles.push({name:file.getName(),id:file.getId(),owner:file.getOwner().getEmail(),currentuser:Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()});
      Logger.log(Utilities.formatString('Name: %s Id: %s Owner: %s CurrentUser: %s', file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getOwner().getEmail(),Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()));
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you. It should only be Logging files that you own. So current user email and owner email should be the same.

I also tested this on a shared folder and it works.  I didn't want to delete anything so a changed a few things and I was just searching for Google Sheets.

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  // Old date is 3 Hours
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
  var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1iJTAdlhCM13c1CB5xMAjtLZlkaPMIlPb');
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);//Just looking for Google Sheets

  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    obj.push({name: file.getName(),id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()}); // Modified
  }
  obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a= new Date(a.date).valueOf();
    var b= new Date(b.date).valueOf();
    return b-a;
  });
  //obj.shift();//I wanted to log all of them
  return obj; // Modified
};

function logFiles() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();// Added
  var obj = getOldFileIDs(); // Modified
  obj.forEach(function(e) { // Modified
    if (e.owner == email) { // Added
      //Drive.Files.remove(e.id); // Modified
      Logger.log('FileName: %s,Owner Email: %s',e.name,e.owner);
    }
  });
};
```